# I want to limit the total number of product in the cart to 3 using woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Do we have any options through which we can limit the number of total items that can be added to cart in woocommerce. I want to limit the total number of product in the cart to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/min-and-max-purchase-for-woocommerce/ or https://wordpress.org/plugins/maximum-purchase-for-woocommerce/ you can also see this one developed by woocommerce: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/minmax-quantities/

Comment: This plugin checks for the total amount/ mix-max quantity of a single product that can be added to the cart. What I am looking for is to restrict the total number of items that can be added to cart. The total can be of any amount but the quantity in the cart shouldn't be more than 3